# Was the chained library at the Citadel modelled after the chained library of Hereford Cathedral?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

A recent question over on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) asks the following: [Why are the books in the Game of Thrones citadel library shelved spine inwards?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/97347/45378) The answers within mainly answer from an out of universe perspective of how this was done in our world as well but one statement caught my eye from [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/97354/45378):

> The GOT library is modelled after the [chained library of Hereford Cathedral](https://www.herefordcathedral.org/chained-library).

As I've commented on the answer this seems like it could be likely, though the Citadel library may just be modelled after chained libraries in general.

Is there any evidence, word from George R. R. Martin or whoever designed the set for the show, that they did indeed model it after this specific library at Hereford Cathedral? If not was it modelled after another library or just the whole chained library system in general?

Comment: possibly worth reading/watching http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20180706-the-ancient-library-where-the-books-are-under-lock-and-key

Comment: +1 for trying to devalidify another post haha